# Why does not wifi hotspot work when I open a game?

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I enable portable hotspot on my Android 4.4 tablet and share its internet with PC. But, after I open a game (Clash of Clans to put it more specifically), it seems that internet sharing is disabled because I have no internet connectivity in PC anymore and have to exit the game to reestablish the connection and remove the yellow warning triangle from the wireless icon in taskbar. Why is this so and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Clash of Clans has the permission to connect and disconnect from Wi-Fi. If it wants to connect, it would have to enable Wi-Fi which would disable hotspot. That' s my guess on what might be happening here.

Comment: But I think I am using cellular network when this happens. Actually, connectivity returns to normal when I exit the game, without hotspot disabled. Should it be a RAM management strategy given that the device has only 1 GB of RAM?